# How do you assign a number in an array a value?

Tags: java, digit

I am trying to convert the tenth digit of an array to a number (10) if it is the value 'x'. 
I have tried...

```
if (array[9] === 'x') {
'x' === 10;
};
```

Thanks

Comment: `===` is for checking equality; `=` is for assignment.

Comment: By using the assignment operator: `=`.

Comment: Java don't even have an `===` operator...

Comment: @Vallentin that's what I thought too :-)

Comment: Unclear if you don't know the difference between Java and JavaScript, or have never read a beginner's book or tutorial. Or Both.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, assuming that `array` is a `char[]`:

```
if (array[9] == 'x') {
    array[9] = 10;
}
```

By the way, the code you posted is not valid for Java. This is not an operator: `===`, we must use `=` for assignment and the trailing `;` after the last `}` is unnecessary.

Comment: I don't know what OP wants but you might want to point out that `array[9] = 10` will assign the value of `(char)10` to that element and that `(char)10` is a whitespace character.

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code already.

```
 if (array[9] == 'x') //Line 1
 {
     array[9] = 10; // Line 2
 }
```

On Line 1 you said `===`. Java uses `==` to check if two primitive values are equal in value.

On Line 2 you used three equal signs again. If you want to reassign a variable, you will need to use ONE equal sign.

Comment: Line 2 also isn't a valid statement. The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable.

Comment: You're right, that is my mistake. You'd have to change the value at index 9 to 10. Thanks for the clarification